# How can i focus on textbox and datagridview at the same time in c#?

Tags: c#

We have textboxs and two datagridview.. When i want to write in textbox1, this textbox1 filter datagridview.... But when i want to use arrows to navigate throw rows we must press two times key down to start.

Comment: You can't focus two controls at the same time.

Comment: Question clearly "need more focus"... Since only one control can have *focus* you should clarify what you want to achieve - there is a good chance that you use well defined "focus" with some other meaning... Please [edit] post to clarify that.

Comment: You can intercept the keyboard events in the text box, and simulate the behaviour you want in some way....

Comment: Thank you very much... I know that can not focus on two controls at the same time but we use one application for my pharmacy when i write in textbox this text box filter my datagridview and one of the rows is fully selected when i press the key down button {down arrow button}... Also the selector is move down and up

Answer (score 0):

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{Down}");
            
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[CurrentRow + 1].Selected = true;
                dataGridView2.Focus();
               
            }

        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && dataGridView2.Rows.Count>0 && textBox1.TextLength>0)
        {
            txtQty.Text = "1";
            dataGridView2.Focus();
            cmbProducts.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtPrice.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            
            txtQty.Focus();

        }
       

    }
```

Comment: It's allowed to self-answer without community wiki post. But can you [edit] your answer to add explaination of the given code ?